# VBA issue with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 that works with InternetExplorerMedium

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I like to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 when I can as it is faster. However, I have not been able to figure out how to use it when I need to interact with the website.
Thats probably for another question.

However, I am having an issue on why I get different URL returned. When I use the following code, I get the required results
...

```
Sub GoogleSfund()

Set objIExplorer = New InternetExplorerMedium

    objIExplorer.Silent = True
    objIExplorer.Visible = False 'for testing change to true

    objIExplorer.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=DWCPF"

    Do While objIExplorer.Busy or Not objIExplorer.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    a = objIExplorer.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("g-card-section")
    pos1 = InStr(a.innerText, "INDEXDJX: DWCPF")
    pos2 = InStr(a.innerText, "Disclaimer")
    b = Mid(a.innerText, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
    b = Replace(b, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
    MsgBox b
    TSP_Test.lblSfund.Caption = b
objIExplorer = ""
End Sub...
```

With (MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0) it does not grab the page with the same URL

```
Sub GoogleSfundFAST()
Dim sSourceUrl As String
Dim HttpReq as Object

Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLH3Doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInstProcDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

sSourceUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=dwcpf"
'sSourceUrl = "https://www.google.com/search"
HttpReq.Open "GET", sSourceUrl, False
HttpReq.send

If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    HttpReq.getAllResponseHeaders
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = HttpReq.responseText
End If

Dim Obj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim Heading As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HD As HTMLElementCollection

Debug.Print HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML

End Sub
```

Any Ideas why it is different?

Comment: A page loaded in a browser can use javascript to access other content (for one or multiple further requests) and build up the page from that content, whereas the same URL loaded using XMLHTTP doesn't do that.  Open (eg) Chrome's developer tools at the Network tab, and watch what happens when you hit that example URL: there are dozens of additional related requests made from your browser.  That's *why* automating the browser is often slower than using XMLHTTP - the browser does more work.

Comment: Thanks Tim you lead me in the right direction. I was able to find the correct URL using Chrome's Developer Tools:)